# Pass JSON output to Another Class -  iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, asihttprequest

I have two classes:

dbConnector - connects to database and retrieves data
viewcontroller - instantiates dbConnector and calls data retrieval functions

The problem I am facing is getting dbConnector to pass the data to the viewcontroller:

dbConnectorClass:

```
#import "dbConnector.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"
#import "JSONKit.h";

@implementation dbConnector
@synthesize data;

//method to 
-(void)getQuestions:(NSString*)sectionId from:(NSString*)url{
    NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:link]; 
    [request setPostValue:sectionId forKey:@"section"]; 
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];    
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *questions = [json objectFromJSONString];
    NSLog(@"%@", questions);
    //need to pass questions to view controller...how??
    [json release];
}

@end
```

viewcontroller class:

```
#import "dbQuestionGetterViewController.h"
#import "dbConnector.h";

@implementation dbQuestionGetterViewController
@synthesize questions, db;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    db = [[dbConnector alloc]init];
    //code to initialise view
    [db getQuestions:@"2" from:@"http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/get_questions.php"];
    //self.questions = arr;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

What I would like is to assign the NSDictionary* questions from dbConnector to the questions pointer synthesized in my viewcontroller.m

How can I get dbConnector to pass the returned JSON string to my view controller viewDidLoad method?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement and delegate protocol for dbConnector class and make the dbQuestionGetterViewController the delegate of the dbConnector instance.

Edit:

[Delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH14-SW1)

[Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH45-SW1)

Edit 2:

In dbConnector.h add before import

```
@protocol dbConnectorDelegate 

-(void)didFinishDownloadData:(NSData*)data;

@end
```

In dbConnector.h in @interface add:

```
id<dbConnectorDelegate> delegate;
```

And declare a new property for delegate

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<dbConnectorDelegate> delegate;
```

In your dbConnector.m file synthesize the delegate property:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

And in requestFinished add

```
[delegate didFinishDownloadData: responseData];
```

By this you are telling to your delegate that you have finish download with the data parameter.

In your dbQuestionGetterViewController.h import the `dbConnector.h` and tell to the dbQuestionGetterViewController that will implement dbConnectorDelegate:

```
@interface dbQuestionGetterViewController : UIViewController<dbConnectorDelegate>
```

And in your dbQuestionGetterViewController.m add

```
- (void)didFinishDownloadData:(NSData*)data{
        NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *questions = [json objectFromJSONString];
        NSLog(@"%@", questions);
        //need to pass questions to view controller...how??
        [json release];
    }
```

And your view did load add:

```
db.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Ok thats what I want but how can I implement this?